# Counting UK Statutory Instruments implemented annually enacting EU legislation?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

Is there a convenient way of determining the number of UK Statutory Instruments implemented annually as a direct result of EU legislation?

[This page](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi) shows the totals, but I cannot see a way of distinguishing those that are implementing EU law.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33768/by-what-process-do-eu-directives-become-uk-national-law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[House of Commons briefing paper #7867](http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/CBP-7867/CBP-7867.pdf) lists all statutory instruments - nearly 8000 of them - which implement EU directives (and occasionally regulations) up to 2017.

It's possible to do an [advanced search on the legislation.gov.uk website, which looks for all SIs which mention the European Communities Act 1972](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/secondary?text=%22European%20Communities%20Act%201972%22). I wouldn't regard this as a complete list, as a small proportion of EU legislation is enacted via Acts of Parliament, but it's better than a list of all SIs!